# K6 - iterate over array, but not for each VU

Tags: k6

I am working on a script to test my infra using [k6](https://k6.io).

I would like each VU be assigned to a previous known `id` obtained from an existing array and that VU execute the instructions from the `default` function only once at the time the VU is created.

How to iterate over this array, get the `id` and use it for each VU created by the script?

The initial idea is bellow, but I am sure it is not correct.

```
export let options = {
    stages: [
        { duration: '10s', target: 1 },
        { duration: '10s', target: 10 },
    ],
};

const ids = [
    {'id':1, 'name':'name1'},
    {'id':3, 'name':'name3'},
    {'id':4, 'name':'name4'},
    {'id':18, 'name':'name18'}];

export default function () {
    for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
        var user = ids[i];
        //do something with user.id
    }
}
```

According to K6 manual, each VU will execute everything is inside the `default` function, but it would make all VU's execute the for loop and it is not the behavior I want.

I want the VU execute what is inside the for, but using a different id for each new VU. Something like bellow:

```
export default function () {
    var user = ids[i];
    //do something with user.id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up solving this specific scenario using a combination of... `scenarios` :-) and the global variable `__VU`.

At the scenario configuration, I said that each VU would iterate only 1 time during all the test and I would launch as much VU's as I had in the `ids` array. This way, each VU would use one of the ids and run the `default` function only 1 time.

Because `__VU` starts from 1, I had also to use `__VU-1` to correctly index the array.

```
const ids = [
    {'id':1, 'name':'name1'},
    {'id':3, 'name':'name3'},
    {'id':4, 'name':'name4'},
    {'id':18, 'name':'name18'}];

export let options = {
    scenarios: {
        stress_test: {
            executor: 'per-vu-iterations',
            vus: ids.length,
            iterations: 1
        }
    }
};

export default function () {
    var user = ids[__VU-1];
    //do something with user.id
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From k6 version 0.34 ,there is a solution for this issue.

```
import exec from "k6/execution";
import { SharedArray } from "k6/data";
import http from "k6/http";


const data = new SharedArray("my dataset", function(){
    const ids = [
        {'id':1, 'name':'name1'},
        {'id':3, 'name':'name3'},
        {'id':4, 'name':'name4'},
        {'id':18, 'name':'name18'}
    ];
    return ids;
})

export const options = {
  scenarios :{
    "use-all-the-data": {
      executor: "shared-iterations",
      vus: data.length,
      iterations: data.length,
      maxDuration: "30s"
    }
  }
}

export default function() {
  // this is unique even in the cloud
  var item = data[exec.scenario.iterationInTest];
  http.post("https://httpbin.test.k6.io/anything?endpoint=amazing", item)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(item))
}
```